# Redirect on successful file upload when creating a new WordPress post using jQuery Form Plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I am trying to use malsup's [jQuery Form Plugin](https://github.com/malsup/form/) to add a percentage progress bar to file uploads. My form also captures post title and content and if everything is completed and submitted successfully a new WordPress post is created.

My form:

```
<input type="text" name="post_title" />
<textarea name="post_text" rows="3"></textarea>
<input type="file" name="post_upload" id="file" />
<input id="submit" name='post_form_subimitted' type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Aside from the form, I have these HTML elements on the page

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div >
    <div class="percent">0%</div >
</div>

<div id="status"></div>
```

My script:

```
<script>
(function() {

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        status.empty();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    success: function() {
        var percentVal = '100%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function() {
        // -- i think this is the part I am struggling with -- //
    }
}); 

})();       
</script>
```

My question is, how can I redirect the user to the post on successful upload? The URL would be `example.com/post_id` where post_id is auto generated on new post creation and will be something like `674`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$last = wp_get_recent_posts( '1');
$last_id = $last['0']['ID'];
?>
```

this will return last post id so put a js code below the form submit code.. than $last_id will be holding the value u want. hope this helps

Comment: If I change the script to "complete: function() { window.location.href = "/376"; }" I can get the redirect working. 376 is hardcoded though so how could I replace this with your $last_id variable?